# How to find partial string match in Angular Firestore?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Give that I have a collection (`airports`) of documents that are of the following structure:

```
id: 1112
city: "Paris"
country: "France"
iata: "CDG"
name: "Paris Charles de Gaulle Airport"
```

Is it possible to query partial string matches within document? Let's say I want to find this document by querying `aull` or `harles` in the airport name... Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

Is not supported natively by firestore, however as mentioned [in their docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search) you can do this by using a third-party search service like [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/).

Here is a small code example

```
var client = algoliasearch(ALGOLIA_APP_ID, ALGOLIA_SEARCH_KEY);
var index = client.initIndex('notes');

// Perform an Algolia search:
// https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/search/
index
  .search({
    query
  })
  .then(function(responses) {
    // Response from Algolia:
    // https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/search/#response-format
    console.log(responses.hits);
  });
```

But on the docs, they have a detailed step by step guide on how to get it working.